# Installing a php application in a windows server 2012, 2008 or 2003

Tags: php

I found too many problems in installing  the application in a local network. I use wampserver as the local server(in my computer only) for my  application. I want to use a windows server 2012,2008 or 2003 to install the application so that it may function in the network I created and different users can access to it. Would you please give me even the link that explains the steps clearly and in details?

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install Microsoft's web platform

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

it will work on server with IIS and on a local desktop with IIS Express.

After you install it, you may add PHP to your server as Fast-CGI application host.

Comment: Thanks, but I 'm new in this domain. Would you please go into details?

Comment: All required details are on Microsoft's page above.